# Dynamic query and dynamic select

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I need to design set of classes that will receive 
Input params and will build dynamic where condition and select . Entity framework will allow to build dynamic where condition but have a problem to dynamically select fields .

Please advice other frameworks that will allow requirement above and will return querable objects by Linq .

For example I have several tables

First table name table1
         Fied           Column1

Second table.    Table2
         Field.          Column2

And so on . I would like to have view defined that will join all tables . I would like to query view 
And dynamically choose columns .

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want to "dynamically select fields"? Or give a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx). This allows you to build queries as a string.